# Get time taken to execute a function in Go

Tags: go

A defer statement defers the execution of a function until the surrounding function returns.
However, if I try to print the time taken to execute the following function, it always prints 0.

```
func sum() {
    start := time.Now()

    //expecting to print non zero value but always gets 0
    defer fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(start))

    sum := 0
    for i := 1; i < 101; i++ {
        sum += i
    }
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

Snippet: https://play.golang.org/p/46dxtS5beET

Comment: This is covered in the tour: https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12 "The deferred call's arguments are evaluated immediately"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The arguments to the deferred function are evaluated at the point the function is deferred. Use the following code to evaluate the elapsed time as you expect:

```
defer func() { fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(start)) }()
```

An [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45766707/5728991) describes how to encapsulate the timing logic in a reusable function.