# get decorated function name in golang

Tags: go, decorator

I am trying to log decorated function name before and after calling it as below.

Is it possible to get the decorated function name `f1` in `decorator` to make it shows `entering f1` and `leaving f1`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func f1() {
    fmt.Println("f1")
}

func decorator(f func()) {
    fmt.Println("entering f.name")
    f()
    fmt.Println("leaving f.name")
}

func main() {
    decorator(f1)

}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54451891/13631587) for an easy way hook enter and exit from within the function.  The answer logs on exit.  Add a print statement to the beginning to the `timer` function to log on enter.

Comment: Note that not all functions have names.

Comment: Not in a nice, supported, compatible way that actually works and works they way you seem to thing it should work .

Comment: please look at `runtime` package, maybe there is something that can help you there.

Comment: @mri1939 yes, I am trying `runtime.Callers` , `runtime.FuncForPC` and `runtime.CallersFrames` and will update if I got some clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the reflect and runtime package for that

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
  "reflect"
  "runtime"
)

func f1() {
  fmt.Println("f1")
}

func decorator(f func()) {
  name := runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(f).Pointer()).Name()
  fmt.Printf("entering f.name:%s\n",name)
  f()
  fmt.Printf("leaving f.name:%s\n",name)
}

func main() {
  decorator(f1)
}
```

```
entering f.name:main.f1
f1
leaving f.name:main.f1
``
```