# How to test Go function execution time using standard lib

Tags: go

I've written the following function that when used with `Defer` will surely do the trick but is there something in standard library I could use for this? I'm looking something similar to Python `timeit` which I could use directly from the shell?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    defer timeTrack(time.Now(), "looptest")
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    var m []int
    for n := range nums {
        if n%2 == 0 {
            m = append(m, n)
        }
    }
}

func timeTrack(start time.Time, name string) {
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("%s took %s", name, elapsed)
}
```

Comment: Seems you are looking for [benchmarks](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks).

Comment: See related / possible duplicate of [Order of the code and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608578/order-of-the-code-and-performance/41608707#41608707).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Go [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) package. For example,

`main.go`:

```
package main

func doStuff() {
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    var m []int
    for n := range nums {
        if n%2 == 0 {
            m = append(m, n)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    doStuff()
}
```

`main_test.go`:

```
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkStuff(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        doStuff()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: main
BenchmarkStuff-4    5000000    276 ns/op    120 B/op    4 allocs/op
```

---

Using the information from the benchmark, you can improve performance. Reduce the number and size of allocations by using an estimate to initialize slice `m`.

```
func doStuff() {
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    m := make([]int, 0, len(nums)/2+1)
    for n := range nums {
        if n%2 == 0 {
            m = append(m, n)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: main
BenchmarkStuff-4    20000000    83.1 ns/op    48 B/op    1 allocs/op
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use testing

```
func BenchmarkFoo(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Foo()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "benchmark"-approach:

1. Name the file %SOMETHING%_test.go
2. Write tests, benchmarks, examples in it as follows:

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "testing"
   )

   func fn() {
       nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
       var m []int
       for n := range nums {
           if n%2 == 0 {
               m = append(m, n)
           }
       }
   }

   func BenchmarkFunc(b *testing.B) {
       for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
           fn()
       }
   }
   ```
3. Open the terminal and execute the following command:

   ```
   go test -bench .
   ```
4. You will see the output like this:

   ```
   goos: darwin
   goarch: amd64
   BenchmarkFunc-2      5000000           360 ns/op         120 B/op          4 allocs/op
   PASS
   ok      command-line-arguments  2.190s
   ```