# Why does `time.Since(start).Seconds()` always return 0?

Tags: go, time

I am on the first chapter [The Go Programming Language (Addison-Wesley Professional Computing Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134190440) and the 3rd exercise in the book asks me to measure code performance using `time`.

So, I came up with the following code.

```golang
start := time.Now()
var s, sep string
for i := 1; i < len(os.Args); i++ {
    s += sep + os.Args[i]
    sep = " "
}
fmt.Print(s)
fmt.Printf("\nTook %.2fs \n", time.Since(start).Seconds())
fmt.Println("------------------------------------------------")
start2 := time.Now()
fmt.Print(strings.Join(os.Args[1:], " "))
fmt.Printf("\nTook %.2fs", time.Since(start2).Seconds())
```

When I ran this code on Windows and Mac, it always return 0.00 second. I added a pause in my code to check whether it's correct and it seems fine. What I don't understand is why it always returns 0.0.

Comment: Why is my question getting downvotes? Please comment so I know what to improve

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is very little code between your start times and the `time.Since()` calls, in the first example just a few string concatenations and an `fmt.Print()` call, in the second example just a single `fmt.Print()` call. These are executed by your computer very fast.

So fast, that the result is most likely less than a millisecond. And you print the elapsed time using the `%.2f` verb, which **rounds the seconds** to 2 fraction digits. Which means if the elapsed time is less than `0.005 sec`, it will be rounded to `0`. This is why you see `0.00s` printed.

If you change the format to `%0.12f`, you will see something like:

```
Took 0.000027348000s 
Took 0.000003772000s
```

Also note that the [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) value returned by [`time.Since()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Since) implements [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer), and it "formats" itself intelligently to a unit that is more meaningful. So you may print it as-is.

For example if you print it like this:

```
fmt.Println("Took", time.Since(start))
fmt.Println("Took", time.Since(start2))
```

You will see an output something like this:

```
Took 18.608µs
Took 2.873µs
```

Also note that if you want to measure the performance of some code, you should use Go's built-in testing and benchmarking facilities, namely the [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) package. For details, see [Order of the code and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608578/order-of-the-code-and-performance/41608707#41608707).